# Выполнение процессов и потоков и роль GIL

Tags: python, многопоточность, процесс, ос, многозадачность

Хочу уточнить, правильно ли я понимаю работу процессов и потоков в ОС.

Предположим, у меня есть **одноядерная система**, на которой я запустил 3 процесса, каждый из которых содержит по 3 потока. Верно ли, что и процессы, и потоки будут выполняться псевдо-параллельно, используя планировщик задач ОС? Если да, то вопрос такой: какую роль в такой системе будет играть глобальная блокировка интерпретатора (GIL) в Python? Она заключается в том, что интерпретатор будет всегда выполнять только одну инструкцию в один момент времени, но из-за ограничений ОС (у нас же одно ядро) получается, что интерпретатор в принципе и без GIL’а не способен нарушить это правило. Глобальная блокировка сильно влияет на выполнение потоков в Python’e, из-за чего они практически неспособны выполнять cpu-bound задач (вычисления, например). Но выходит, что из-за того, что ядро одно и процессор в принципе в любом ЯП будет выполнять по одной инструкции в один момент времени, тот же, например, C# или C++ также будет страдать и плохо выполнять параллельные вычисления в потоках?

Хорошо, теперь предположим, что у меня **система с четырёх-ядерным процессором** и все те же 3 процесса и 3 потока на каждый. Правильно ли я понимаю, что в таком случае процессор сможет выполнять до 4-х потоков одновременно? Допустим, 2 потока из одного процесса и 2 из другого. Это если речь не про Python и GIL. В Python'e, соответственно, все также будет выполняться по одному потоку в единицу времени.

Если есть ещё какие-то замечания по этому поводу, буду рад почитать. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что касается выполнения на одноядерной системе, то все практически так, как вы описали в вопросе.

Один только важный момент, про роль GIL в таком случае остается важной. GIL защищает внутренние структуры интерпретатора при выполнении многопоточного приложения.

Интерпретатор выполняет такие шаги в цикле:

1. читает питон код, проверяет что он синтаксически правильный
2. генерирует для соответствующий байт-код для виртуальной машины
3. виртуальная машина исполняет байт-код

Планировщик ОС может в любой момент переключить выполнение на любой любой поток любого процесса. Это в частности означает, что он может переключить выполнение с одного потока того самого процесса на другой в середине исполнения этого цикла или в середине исполнения уже машинных инструкций на шаге 3. Структуры данных самого интерпретатора не являются потокобезопасными и GIL как раз используется для защиты их целостности. Т.е. переключение между потоками возможно только в строго определенных точках исполнения интерпретатора.

Для системы с четырех-ядерным процессором, если процессы не питон, то сможет выполняться четыре потока в сумме. Если же процессы питон, то GIL не даст исполнятся больше чем одному потоку каждого процесса. Поэтому максимально сможет исполняться только три потока одновременно - по одному для процесса.

Comment: Спасибо, теперь все более понятно! Я немного неправильно задал вопрос и забыл уточнить, что во второй части я не конкретно про Python и GIL, а в целом про выполнение :)