# Почему потоки не работают параллельно python threading

Tags: python, многопоточность, threading

У меня есть сложная задача с большим кол-вом вычислений. Я хочу её оптимизировать и распределить по потокам.
Тестовая болванка:

```
import threading

test = 0


def my_func():
    c = 43243423 ** 543536  # 'сложные вычисления...'
    global test
    test += c
    print(f"{threading.current_thread().name} finished")
    barrier.wait()


barrier = threading.Barrier(6)
for i in range(5):
    threading.Thread(target=my_func).start()

print("created")
barrier.wait()
print(test)
```

На выходе я получаю :

```
Thread-1 finished
Thread-2 finished
Thread-3 finished
Thread-4 finished
createdThread-5 finished
```

По моей задумке все потоки должны выполнять вычисления параллельно, следовательно они должны завершится примерно в 1 момент, но этого не происходит. Как заставить их работать одновременно?

Comment: Я бы отошел от использования модуля threading и посмотрел бы в сторону multiprocessing, там намного лучше все организовано

Comment: Вероятно, потому что операция возведения в степень не отпускает глобальную блокировку интерпретатора (GIL), и из-за блокировки работать может только один поток. Если вы попробуете выполять операции, которые отпускают GIL (например, чтение файла или скачивание чего-то по сети или перенос вычислений в сторонний сишный модуль типа numpy), то, возможно, ситуация изменится

Comment: Во первых если у вас один процессор для работы с задачей, то тред вам не поможет и да математические операции не отпускают GIL насколько я знаю. Для вычислений в многопотоке (на нескольких процессорах) я бы рекомендовал лучше использовать Pool из aiomultiprocess в асинхронном режиме.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Выполнение процессов и потоков и роль GIL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1285122/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%86%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c-gil)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо всем за советы. В данной ситуации правильно будет использовать multiprocessing

```
import multiprocessing


def my_func():
    c = 43243423 ** 546234  # 'сложные вычисления...'
    print(f"{multiprocessing.current_process().name} finished")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(5):
        multiprocessing.Process(target=my_func).start()
```

Ссылочки:
https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/458694/
[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1285122/Выполнение-процессов-и-потоков-и-роль-gil](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1285122/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-gil)

Comment: Тогда уж Pool удобнее оттуда использовать